# Offset playback of two videos when drawing canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-video

It's my first post on Stackoverflow! I hope this is clear, and thanks in advance for your help.

I am drawing two videos to canvas, and recording the canvas for a single video for playback and review.

video1 is a video from our server.
video2 is the user's webcam feed.

**The issue:**
The two videos are not entirely synced due to some delay in the webcam capture.
I am trying to figure out how to delay the ctx.DrawImage of video1 by a "x" milliseconds so that I can get the two videos to appear on the canvas more synchronized, making the final recording look more synchronized.

Here is my code for drawing to the canvas.

```
// Draw two videos to one canvas

$(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video1 = document.getElementById('teachervid');
  var video2 = document.getElementById('studentvideo');

  video1.addEventListener('play', function() {
    var $this = this; //cache
     (function loop() {
      if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
        ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0, 960, 540);
        setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
      }
    })();
  }, 0);
  
  
  video2.addEventListener('play', function() {
    var $this = this; //cache
    (function loop() {
      if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
        ctx.drawImage($this, 960, 0, 960, 540);
        setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
      }
    })();
  }, 0);
  
  
});
```

To be clear, I am not trying to change the frame rate, simply offset the start points of the two videos so that video 1 is drawn X milliseconds after video2 is drawn. I assume I will need to tweak and test what X should be once I figure out how.

Note, Keep in mind that I am new to JS and programming when responding.

Cheers!